# Assigning JQuery events to custom object methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-mobile

I'm creating an app using JQuery (Mobile) and I'm facing a problem with the structure of JQuery events. I defined a dummy "class" like this:

```
MyClass = function()
{
    this.property = initvalue;

    this.foo = function()
    {
        alert("That's my property = " + this.property);
    }
}
```

Then I defined an object based on MyClass:

```
var obj1 = new MyClass();
```

The problem comes when I use obj1.foo() as a callback function to be informed on an event, for example:

```
$(element).click(obj1.foo);
```

or

```
$(element).load(URL, obj1.foo);
```

When foo() is executed, "this" refers to the element, not to the object "obj1", and of course I can't access the object's "property" with a self reference. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQUery's `proxy` method:

```
$(element).load(URL, $.proxy(obj1.foo, obj1));
```

This will assign the `obj1` context to your method.

Answer (score 0):

You can [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the method to its instance:

```
$(element).click(obj1.foo.bind(obj1));
```

The `.bind()` method returns a function, so you are still passing a function to the jQuery method, but that function will have its context bound to whatever you pass to `.bind()`.

If you need to support older browsers, you can use the polyfill given on the MDN article linked to previously, or you can use the jQuery [`$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the click event to an anonymous function that references a cached version of `this` in the context of your object.

```
var myClass = this;
$(element).click(function () { myClass.foo(); });
```

In general it's more performant to use this method over library-provided alternatives like $.bind, $.proxy, and _.bindAll (though in your current example I think the performance would be comparable). See [this article on context binding](http://freshbrewedcode.com/jimcowart/2013/02/12/getting-into-context-binds/).